# Update Firebase from watchOs 6 independent application

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, watchos, watchos-6

I went through this link https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios and I only came across the latest added feature to send Push Notifications using the new FCM.

I also want to update the database and change the values of fields in an array (`arrayValues`), which doesn't seem possible using the REST API and updateMask.

Is it possible to update a Firebase database/Cloud Firestore directly from a watchOS 6 application ?

*Note: I am using Swift and SwiftUI for my application. The application is independent.*

Comment: Hi, i reached to this question from google. Did you find any solution?

Comment: It doesn't look possible using the REST API. I ended up using Google Cloud Functions and sending a simple HTTPS POST request to the function with my data/update information.